# How can define enumerator in Methods?

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys, st

There is a problem when u define an `enum` in a `method`.

I was trying to do this:

```
VAR
    enumA:(A,B,C);
END_VAR
```

and there is the compiler reaction when I used this in `TwinCAT3 Shell` **(TcXaeShell)**.
[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What comes to mind is using `VAR_INST` instead of `VAR` in the declaration part. Unfortunately I'm unable to verify if it works, as I don't have access to PC with TwinCAT at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't work with VAR_INST either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use global enumerations in methods. It's one of the limitations with local enumerations.

https://alltwincat.com/2021/11/16/local-enumerations/

Answer (score 2):

You should first define variable type as enumeration in DUT

```
TYPE MyEnum:
    (A, B, C)
END_TYPE
```

Then in a program you can declare variable of that type

```
VAR
    enum: MyEnum;
END_VAR
```

Inside the program if you want to compare it.

```
IF enum = MyEnum.C THEN
    // Do something
END_IF;
```

Comment: The question was meant to be "How to define *local* enums in methods", so @Jakob gave the more correct answer: "You can't". Though this might still help someone new if they don't know how to define global enums.

Comment: "In a method" is a ritorical part of the question. He asked "how to define enum in a method"  rather than "How to define enum" not because he knew how to define enum globally.  By the nature of his question it is obvious that he does not know how to define them at all. So my unswer is direct to this question from my perspective of view.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov tnx for taking your time on this question and sorry for misunderstanding the question, I can ask my question in a more specific way by this "How can define enumeration `locally` in Methods?", by the way, your answer may help anyone who looking for a solution for this problem so this is good to keep this answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve run into this issue before.  You must declare the local enumeration in the variables section of the **function block**.  Then you can use it in the **methods** of the function block.